# How do I remove stop words in RDD PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, rdd

How do I remove the stop words in PySpark RDD?

```
my_doc = sc.parallelize([("Alex Smith", 101, ["i", "saw", "a", "sheep"]), ("John Lee", 102, ["he", "likes", "ice", "cream"] )])
```

I have the following RDD below:

```
(("Alex Smith", 101, ["I", "saw", "a", "sheep"]), ("John Lee", 102, ["He", "likes", "ice", "cream"]))
```

I want to remove the stop words in the x[2], like "a", "he", "i", etc.

**After removing the stop words, it should look like this below:**

```
(("Alex Smith", 101, ["saw", "sheep"]), ("John Lee", 102, ["likes", "ice", "cream"]))
```

Comment: Why do you need to use RDD API? Why you don't use DataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

Map to rdd for create new elements with filtered value.

```
stop_words = ['i', 'a', 'he']
my_doc.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], list(filter(lambda word: word.lower() not in stop_words, x[2])))).collect()

[('Alex Smith', 101, ['saw', 'sheep']),
 ('John Lee', 102, ['likes', 'ice', 'cream'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to use DataFrame APIs instead of RDD API - in this case the data won't need to be sent to Python process for filtering as everything will stay inside the JVM, and Catalyst will be able to better optimize it.

For filtering of the array elements you can use the [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.filter) function, like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alex Smith", 101, ["i", "saw", "a", "sheep"]),
                            ("John Lee", 102, ["he", "likes", "ice", "cream"] )],
                           schema="name string, id int, words array<string>")
stop_words = ["he", "i", "a", "the"] # ...
df2 = df.select("name", "id",
    F.filter("words", lambda x: ~F.lower(x).isin(stop_words)).alias("words"))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

and it will give you desired answer:

```
+----------+---+-------------------+
|name      |id |words              |
+----------+---+-------------------+
|Alex Smith|101|[saw, sheep]       |
|John Lee  |102|[likes, ice, cream]|
+----------+---+-------------------+
```

Main piece of it is `~F.lower(x).isin(stop_words))` -> this will apply standard `.isin` function against given list of the stop words and negate the result with `~`.